# combining LPCWSTR with another string

Tags: c++

I have a class that needs to save a file, the constructor gets a LPWSTR called fullPath, then i tried to do this (curPath is a LPCWSTR class variable):

```
curPath = (std::wstring(fullPath) + L".ip").c_str();
```

but it ends up being gibberish. Meanwhile this works:

```
auto cp = std::wstring(fullPath) + L".ip";
curPath = cs.c_str();
```

while it seems to me they should essentially do the same thing. Whats up with that?

Comment: You have a typo in the last line, don't you?

Comment: `(std::wstring(fullPath) + L".ip").c_str()` will have an `std::wstring` constructed temporarily then destroyed. The pointer you get (`c_str()`) will be rubbish, as you've noted. But by placing the result into a variable that's scoped correctly, the string will hang around long enough for you to use it meaningfully.

Comment: oh yes typo.
I need for the string to stick around for quite a while since I'll be deleting and remaking the file while the class is being used. Should I make the std::wstring a class variable instead of a LPWSTR and use its c_str() function each time i need it instead?

Comment: `private: std::wstring m_curPath;` might be the way to go. Or it might not. It depends what you need it for.

Comment: The key here is that `curPath` depends on the `wstring` object staying in existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temporary std::wstring created by the expression `(std::wstring(fullPath) + L".ip")` will be destroyed after the expression is evaluated. 
Using the internal memory of this temporary (exposed by c_str) is undefined behavior and a bug.

In the second expression you keep the result in the auto variable cp. So until the end of the current scope you are allowed to use the internal memory of variable cp. Once the scope ends cp is will be destroyed and its memory released.